# RES_NOT_FOUND in JSF

Tags: css, eclipse, jsf, jboss, facelets

Iv read a lot of posts but no success in fixing this. A help please....

Eclipse Juno / JSF

Project Structure :
[image]

teste.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html[
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> 
    <!ENTITY copy "&#169;">
] >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
  <h:outputScript library="js" name="slides.min.jquery.js"/>
  <h:graphicImage value="images/blog.png" />
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/estilo.css"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
  #{javax.faces.resource}
  </h:body>
  </html>
```

The output is :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND">
```

The same res_not_found  to js and image

pom.xml  :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.14</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.23</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.23</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>rome</groupId>
    <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<!-- REPOSITORIOS MAVEN -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-repo</id>
        <name>Jboss Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- -CONFIGURANDO PLUGIN PARA GERACAO DOCUMENTAÇÃO -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>/srv/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <locales>pt-BR</locales>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <descriptorRefs> <descriptorRef> jar-with-dependencies </descriptorRef> 
                    </descriptorRefs> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/abc/resources
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <!-- URL to access the web module -->
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Ive tried a lot of settings for h:outputStyleSheet but with no success.....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Resources` folder must be inside the `webapp` folder, not in the root `main` package.

[image: resources folder inside webapp]

and keep your code the same

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/estilo.css"/>
```

Do not use the css as a library.

See More:

- [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: When I create a maven java project it automatically created the resources outside webapp and I have another project with resources outside webapp but I dont know how this project is getting me this error

Comment: The resources folder in the main root is used for messages bundles `.properties` files for example, not for web resources.

Comment: See this link also: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/

Comment: You are totally right, please downvote me, this way Ill get mor payattention on that. thanks so much @Hatem Aliman